# Java process to consume configure RAM and CPU during specific time

Tags: java, memory, cpu-usage, ram

I would like to know if there is an improved way of implementing a process which consume a configured amount of RAM and CPU in Java during a specific amout of time. 
For now the only idea I've come up with is to create several threads and when the configured limit is reached sleep them and so on until the specific amount of time is over, but there may be better ways of doing this that I don't know.

Thank you!

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - can you please elaborate your specific use case? If you sleep some threads, other threads will consume that CPU, so I don't think that will help. But it depends on your actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: **Implement a process which consumes a configured amount of RAM and CPU in Java during a specific amout of time** This is what I'm supposed to do. But you are right I have to think of another way

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the definition of _XY problem_ above. Or is this an assignment?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see the link. Yes it's an assignment